# Unit-testing functions with void pointers in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, memory-management, googletest, void-pointers

I am a Junior Software Engineer at my day job, working with C#/WPF/Prism, and I have been trying to teach myself other languages and libraries in my spare time to expand my horizons. I have recently been working on C++ while unit testing via Google's Testing and Mocking libraries, and have been doing relatively well in transferring from the C# mindset into the C++ world. While some concepts, like polymorphism and interfaces, made perfect sense moving from C# some of them are a bit puzzling for myself, such as pointer arithmetic. I have recently been working on the lower levels of memory , which is something I never get to see in C#, and have begun writing memory allocators for a three dimensional simulation project I have been working on for fun in my spare time. Which brings me to my question.

I have a function which looks like this :

```
    inline u8 AlignForwardAdjustment(const void* address, u8 alignment)
    {
        u8 adjustment = alignment - (reinterpret_cast<uptr>(address)& static_cast<uptr>(alignment - 1));

        if (adjustment == alignment)
        {
            return 0; //already aligned
        }

        return adjustment;
    }
```

I didn't write this myself, as I found it as part of a guide I have been using to learn how to do manual memory allocators. However, as a part of understanding this subject more I was trying to write unit tests to prove that my allocators work, starting at the lowest level I could find.

This is one of my helper functions for Aligning memory, and it both takes and returns a void*. From what I understand this means that it is returning a pointer of some unformatted or type-unknown block of memory, which makes sense in this context. My question is, is there any way to write a unit, or integration test for this sort of method? In C# I generally try to test any function which I can reach from outside the class, but I honestly do not know how I would write a test which hands in a Void* (set as a value I would expect) and then is capable of making sure the returned pointer was aligned correctly.

Is there any type of cast I can do to pass say a Uint to a void* and just check the math on the other end? Or, should i just write a function like this off as untestable? Any help would be most appreciated, or even a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry new to the site and don't have enough rep to up-vote your comment apparently. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lookup intptr_t. - kec

Kec was absolutely right! The answer was as simple as :

```
const intptr_t given = 30;
const intptr_t expected = 2;

auto returnedValue = pointerMath::AlignForwardAdjustment((void*)given, 8);

EXPECT_EQ(expected, returnedValue);
```

This gives a nice reproducible setup and result for a unit test.

Thanks again kec! Would have marked your comment as the answer, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Comment: Whether or not you need that cast depends on the type of `blah` and what you want to do with `castBackOut`. BTW, conversion to `void *` is implicit in C++, so you probably don't need it.

Comment: Is it? When I try to pass in castedPtr without the cast to void* it complains that it is looking for a const void*.

Comment: Whoops that's a copy paste bug. castedPtr is an intptr_t its supposed to be startingPointer in this particular code sample, but I forgot to change it. Editing now! Now I understand why you asked what blah was... it was the variable I used in my editor when I was testing this.

Comment: Ah, yes, in that case you do need the cast. Conversion from any pointer type to `void *` is implicit, but not from integer types. Conversion back from `void *` to a pointer requires a cast, though.

Comment: Gotcha, so I was going about it the right way, going to update this code to be my actual test and put this one to bed. Thanks for all of the help!